# When Google Play In-app Billing V.3 is not supported

Tags: android, in-app-billing

In Google Play, In-app Billing V.3 there is an option to check if it's supported on user device. Using [isBillingSupported](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html) method.

What do I do if it's not supported. Can I send the user to update his device(If yes, so how?)? What can I do to enable him purchasing from me?

Answer (score 4):

InAppBilling v3 requires:

- Google Play client version 3.9.16 or higher
- Google Play client version 3.10.10 or higher for subscriptions

If it is not supported, I would recommend to ask the user to update its Google Play client. Another solution would be to fallback on InAppBilling V2 (requires Google Play version 3.5 or higher).

Most users are already running Google Play client version 3.9.16 or higher.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to programmatically check for the Google Play Client version? I assume is not the same as Play Store or Play Services version.

Comment: What is google play client ?