# "in-app billing version 3 NOT supported" with up to date Play Store

Tags: android, xamarin, in-app-billing

I'm integrating in-app billing to my Xamarin.Android application. I tested the API using Google test products (android.test.purchased and others) and it worked just fine. After doing some testing I started receiving the following error on the `OnInAppBillingError` event.

**ERROR:** *In-app billing version 3 NOT supported for com.example.appname*

**com.example.appname** is the bundle id of my app.

I found this error on the internet ([this is the closest match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045894/when-google-play-in-app-billing-v-3-is-not-supported)) and the solution is to update Google Play Client. I have the latest possible GPC (version 5.9.12).

The weird thing is that I started receiving this error after some successful tests. And I receive it even when my phone is not connected to the internet. This suggest that the billing SDK is checking for something missing on my phone.

For the first round of tests I used a **MotoG 1st Gen running Android 4.4.4, and Google Play Client 5.9.12** (this is the test that first worked and then error started showing). Then I decided to use two more devices and it worked on a **Samsung S4 (Android 4.4.2, GPC 5.9.12)** and failed again on a **Samsung S2 (Android 4.1.2, GPC 5.7.10)**.

**EDIT:** After a few days the error started showing on the **Samsung S4** (didn't make any changes to the billing code, it just stopped working). I also used a **Samsung S5** without luck.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a user with this issue on Android 9 on a Note 9. They were able to make other purchases, they can use in app purchases just fine on another app I have, just not on the one that uses the latest billing library.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the issue continued to happen in some devices until I left the project. I'm sorry I cannot be of help

Answer (score 57):

I get In-app billing version 3 NOT supported error when the user is not signed into google play.  Ensure a user is logged into google play on the device.

Update 2023:  Note that you might also get the error "Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3" when the user is not logged in to the play store.

Comment: Should I log in with a google account that has payment method enabled? Just having play service isn't enough?

Comment: Yes - The user has to be logged in to the play store with the ability to purchase.

Comment: Hmm, seems like I can never do that due to where I'm born and live :)

Comment: I don't follow your use case but ..... you can always handle the error gracefully and tell the user that in app purchases are not supported.

Comment: How can I check if the user is logged into google play?

Answer (score 4):

Try "Clear Data" and then "Force stop" for Google Play app.

Comment: Not working. I cleared data on both apps and stopped Google Play.