# Android Studio - BillingClient not supported error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-billing, billingclient

I get this error in my log when running my app:

```
W/BillingClient: In-app billing API version 3 is not supported on this device.
```

I recently added in app purchase. Running in simulator.

Any ideas why that is? This is what I have implemented in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.2.1'
```

Comment: Use a physical device... or use a google play enabled emulator

Comment: @PraveenSP I do not have a physical device for Android. How do I know if the simulator is/is not enabled for google play?

Comment: Check this ....https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: @PraveenSP Weird. I just tried this and added Pixel 3 with system image "Q", where it says: "We recommend these Google Play images because this device is compatible with Google Play". But when running my app I still get the error: `W/BillingClient: In-app billing API version 3 is not supported on this device.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["in-app billing version 3 NOT supported" with up to date Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180743/in-app-billing-version-3-not-supported-with-up-to-date-play-store)

Comment: @PraveenSP The error got away when I logged into my google account on the new emulator, but nothing happens when I press the buy button. I also tried with this project: https://github.com/mehfal/android (TestApp 3.zip).

Comment: Nothing Happened ? Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @PraveenSP The purchase does not execute. There should come a box up to confirm the purchase or something, but nothing..

Comment: @PraveenSP EDIT: I get error message: `W/BillingClient: Please fix the input params. SKU can't be null.`. Even tho my app is live rn.