# Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3 with updated Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-services, play-billing-library

I'm using the Google Play Billing Library to offer some in-app purchases in my app. Everything is working correctly, but I'm receiving the error "Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3" on Crashlytics from some users, mainly using Samsung devices.

I've searched for similar issues and I found out that it can be caused either by having an outdated version of the Google Play Store installed or by not beign logged in with the Google account. The problem is that in many of the cases reported, the installed Play Store version is up-to-date and the account is correctly signed-in, because the first connection to the Billing Service is successfull.

For example, a user that had installed version `20.39.15` of Play Services and `22.4.29-21` of Play Store, had this kind of error flow:

- Instantiate `BillingClient`
- Call `billingClient.startConnection`
- Received callback `onBillingSetupFinished` with response code `OK`
- Query purchases and get successfull response

Then after a few seconds:

- Received **3 calls** to `onBillingServiceDisconnected` (this method does nothing in my implementation)
- Received a call to `onBillingSetupFinished` with `responseCode` 3 and `debugMessage`: "Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3"

This is part of the code I'm using, I've omitted the logging for clarity:

```kotlin
class BillingManager(
    private val application: Application
) : PurchasesUpdatedListener, BillingClientStateListener {

...

    init {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(application.applicationContext)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(this)
                .build()
        connectToPlayBillingService()
    }

    private fun connectToPlayBillingService() {
        if (!billingClient.isReady) {
            billingClient.startConnection(this)
        }
    }

    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            queryPurchasesAsync()
        } else {
            handleBillingException(BillingException("Billing connection error", billingResult))
        }
    }

   override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
        Log.w(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected")
    }

...

}
```

Is this an issue with Samsung devices? Why do I receive multiple calls to `onBillingSetupFinished` when I call `startConnection` just once?

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of users in Asia (Singapore, Malaysia, Thailand, actually Australia too) get this error even when Google Play is up to date and they have a valid payment set up.  Haven't been able to solve it. :(

Comment: I am stuck too. Running on One Plus 7 with latest play store app. I am practically stuck now and no solution anywhere. This is the most frustrating part of android dev. None of their error messages mean anything.

Comment: This happens on play store simulator API 32. play store version Version: 33.4.09-21 ... Looks like we are doomed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["in-app billing version 3 NOT supported" with up to date Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180743/in-app-billing-version-3-not-supported-with-up-to-date-play-store)

Comment: any news on this issue?